# Avoid nested for loops when summing over matrix indices

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a fairly simply computation I need to do, but I cannot figure out how to do it in a way that is even close to efficient. I have a large nxn matrix, and I need to compute the following:

[image]

I'm still fairly inexperienced at coding, and so the only way that comes to my mind is to do the straightforward thing and use 3 for loops to move across the indexes:

```
sum=0
for(i in 1:n)
{
    for(j in 1:n)
    {
        for(k in 1:n)
        {
           sum = sum + A[i,j]*A[j,k]
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say, for any decent size matrix this takes forever to run. I know there must be a better, more efficient way to do this, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Well that's outstanding, thank you!

Comment: @nicola Why aren't you posting your great comments?

Comment: @DavidArenburg tx, done, I was away from my pc. Very glad you appreciate my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't consider the `k` and `i` sums, you can realise that you are just doing the matrix product of `A` with itself. Such product in R is obtained through the `%*%` operator. After calculating this matrix, you just need to sum all the elements together:

```
 sum(A %*% A)
```

should give the result you are seeking.